# If statement for ForFiles based on file date

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, forfiles

I have a batch file that I call via SQL server agent.

Currently I have:

```
ForFiles /p "C:\folder\subfolder" /d -7 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

The command works fine if there is a file older than 7days.

If there isn't a file that meets the criteria then the script fails causing SQL to report failure.

Ideally I need to add and if statement that if a file exists that is older than 7 days then carry out the delete command otherwise ignore it.

Any guidance?

Comment: Have you not tried `if exist @file del @file` inside of the `forfiles` loop?

Comment: @aschipfl the `FORFILES` command will output **ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.** if it cannot find any files based on the options used.

Comment: True, @Squashman! So `forfiles ... 2> nul || exit /B 0` could do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd /d C:\folder\subfolder
SET _CmdResult=NONE
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ('forfiles -p "C:\folder\subfolder" -s -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c del @file" 2^>^&1 ^| FINDSTR ERROR') DO SET _CmdResult=%%a
IF "%_CmdResult%" == "ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria." ( 
    SET errorlevel=0 
 ) ELSE ( 
    SET errorlevel=1
 )
IF "%_CmdResult%" == "NONE" SET errorlevel=0
```

it checks for an error, and will put the error into a variable and then we set the errorlevel to zero if found.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it inside a `FOR /F` command an redirect standard error to NUL.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('forfiles /P "C:\folder\subfolder" /d -7  2^>nul') do DEL "%%~G"
```

Comment: This will set the exit code to `1` when the `for /F` loop doesn't iterate, which is detected by the SQL tool...

Comment: @aschipfl I tested it at the cmd line and checked the errorlevel and it was always zero.

Comment: Yes, `ErrorLevel` is `0`, but the exit code is `1`, because `for /F` is one of the few commands that do not set both values to te same value; I forgot about that, sorry! Put the whole loop in parentheses and append `|| rem/`, then `ErrorLevel` becomes `1` too...

Comment: @aschipfl thanks much.  Thought I knew just about everything about batch files after 50 years on this planet.

Comment: @aschipfl I tried your code option in your comment below the question but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Are you talking about the `exit /B 0` stuff? well, I have to admit I didn't test it (as I'm on mobile right now) and I don't know exactly how `forfiles` handles the exit code...

Comment: Hello, I tried this and the result was the same within SQL. The solution above worked. Thanks